# jira rest-api attach file to issue using powershell

Tags: powershell, jira-rest-api

I want to attach a file to an jira issue , i am able to do it with postman, but have tried several ways without break through. 
my code looks like this

```
function ConvertTo-Base64($string) {
$bytes  = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($string);
$encoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes);
return $encoded;
}

function Get-HttpBasicHeader([string]$username, [string]$password, $Headers = @{}) {
    $b64 = ConvertTo-Base64 "$($username):$($Password)"
    $Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic $b64"
    $Headers["X-Atlassian-Token"] = "nocheck"
return $Headers
}



$restapiuri = "https://xxxx.xxxx.com/rest/api//2/issue/test-8442/attachments"
$headers = Get-HttpBasicHeader "xxxxxx" "xxxxxxxx"


$myfile = "C:\TEMP\out.txt"
$fileBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($myfile);
$fileEnc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('UTF-8').GetString($fileBytes);
$boundary = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
$LF = "`r`n";



$body = '(
            "--$boundary",
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"fil`"; filename=`"out.txt`"",
            "Content-Type: application/octet-stream$LF",
            $fileEnc,
            "--$boundary--$LF"
           ) -join $LF

 '


Invoke-RestMethod -uri $restapiuri  -Headers $headers  -Method POST -ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=`"$boundary`"" -Body $body
```

**In postman i am doing a post request with** 
*Authorization 
Basic Auth 
headers
header X-Atlassian-Token = o-check
Content-Type = multipart/form-data
Body form-data
key     value
file    filepath*

The powershell doesn't return any errors, but it does not attach any file either 
I have tried several examples without luck so if any of you have any ideas on have to do this in powershell i would be glad.

I am on powershell version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision

---

5      1      14409  1018

Comment: URL looks weird on line beginning with `$restapiuri = `, note the doubled up `/` near the 2.  `/api//2/issue/`

Comment: Thanks, i corrected it but it still dont upload any file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following that looks to be a good fit for this scenario.

```
function Upload-JiraFile($jiraTicket, $filepath, $authorization)
{
    $wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
    $wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", $authorization)
    $wc.Headers.Add("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck") 
    $wc.UploadFile("$URIPath/issue/$jiraTicket/attachments", $filepath)
}
```

Here is how you could use it with the bare minimal modification to the code you have today:

```
$URIPath = "https://xxxx.xxxx.com/rest/api/2"
Upload-JiraFile -JiraTicket test-8442 -FilePath c:\temp\MyJpg.jpg `
   -Authorization $Headers["Authorization"]
```

Excerpted [from this thread.](https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/powershell-invoke-restmethod-uploading-new-attachment-to-jira-ticket/6184)